# Stratum Server with twisted: Worker Autoadd enabled, nut not working?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, server, stratum, websockets

I have a problem with Twisted, It works but I have set the config.py the Param for USERS_AUTOADD = True but it doesnt works?

Already restarted my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, and Stratum too, but it never works. If you create the Worker in the Pool MPOS Frontend it's working but if I don't Stratum don't add these workers automaticly, why?

Can you help me?

Thanks,